# Is it possible to use .Max in Postman test script

Tags: json, environment-variables, postman

How to get max id in Postman script? i.e., here, in such case, I want `2` as result. If in future this has more id, then I want `.Max` of it.

```
"collection:"[
  {
    "Id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Script:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var result = jsonData.collection[0].id; // This gives me 1
var result = jsonData.collection[1].id; // This gives me 2 and so on.
```

How to get my desired result?

One way to do this is as following but not sure if there is a better way to do that.

```
var maxId = jsonData.collection.length - 1;
var maximumId = jsonData.collection[maxId].id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `jsonData.collection` to extract all the `Id` values; then you can simply take the [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) of them:

```js
const jsonInput = `{
  "collection": [
    {
      "Id": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 4
    },
    {
      "Id": 2
    }
  ]
}`;

const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonInput);

const maxId = Math.max(...jsonData.collection.map(o => o.Id))

console.log(maxId)
```